# Transposing a simple dataset in r

Tags: r

I'm trying to do some simple transposing - I have two columns in a data set, shown below:

```
+----+-------+-------+
|    | key   | value |
|    | <int> | <dbl> |
|  1 | 4181  | 28    |
|  2 | 4181  | 48    |
|  3 | 1229  | 20    |
|  4 | 1229  | 41    |
|  5 | 3302  | 76    |
|  6 | 3302  | 111   |
|  7 | 4105  | 83    |
|  8 | 4105  | 44    |
|  9 | 6544  | 18    |
| 10 | 6544  | 43    |
+----+-------+-------+
```

I want the key to become the column and the value to fill the resulting cells. There are 400 records for every unique instance of the key variable. I haven't been able to get this to work with either spread or reshape. Spread tells me there are duplicate values, so I must not be understanding how the function works.

Edit: I realized my explanation and dataset were unclear. The key column has duplicate identifiers, but they all have the same number of corresponding values (each number in the key column appears 400 times with corresponding numbers in the values column). This is why I'm having trouble using dplyr::spread. I'd like my output to look like the below:

```
  4181 1229 3302 4105 6544
1 28   20   76   83   18    
2 48   41   111  44   43
```

Comment: *"I want the key to become the column and the value to fill the resulting cells."* But `key` *is* the column, isn't it? Can you update your question to include your expected outcome?

Comment: @MauritsEvers I've updated both the table and output to show what I'm going for. My previous example was misleading because it didn't contain duplicate values in the key field, which is why dplyr::spread has trouble with what I'm going for.

Comment: Please take a look at my updated answer below. You can still use `spread` if you ensure proper grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution in base R using `unstack`:

```
t(unstack(rev(df)));
#    130 136 1122 1229 2612 3302 4105 4181 4622 6544
#res 111  43   48   20   44   76   83   28   41   18
```

---

### Update

To deal with duplicate keys, here is a `dplyr`/`tidyr` solution:

```
library(tidyverse);
df %>% group_by(key) %>% mutate(i = row_number()) %>% spread(key, value) %>% select(-i);
## A tibble: 2 x 5
#  `1229` `3302` `4105` `4181` `6544`
#   <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
#1     20     76     83     28     18
#2     41    111     44     48     43

# Sample data
df <- read.table(text =
    "     key    value
      1  4181   28
      2  4181   48
      3  1229   20
      4  1229   41
      5  3302   76
      6  3302   111
      7  4105   83
      8  4105   44
      9  6544   18
     10  6544   43 ", header = T, row.names = 1)
```

Explanation: Group by `key`, number the rows in every group, then `spread` into wide, and remove the within-group row number.

Answer (score 3):

The 'spread`function from 'tidyr` will do the trick.

```
#Data 
 df <-  read.table(text = "key value
    4181    28
    1122    48
    1229    20
    4622    41
    3302    76
     130   111
    4105    83
    2612    44
    6544    18
   136    43", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(tidyr)
> spread(df, key, value)
#  130 136 1122 1229 2612 3302 4105 4181 4622 6544
$1 111  43   48   20   44   76   83   28   41   18

The key value has been changed to columns and value has been assigned properly.
```

Comment: You're absolutely right that this would have been the solution with my first dataset example. However, because my dataset contained duplicate keys I had to give the credit to Maurits.

Comment: @jstauss No worries. I'm happy solutions worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you meant you want the column names (or header) to be the key. At which point R's transpose function `t()` will do the job for you.

```
#Set up example data frame
key = seq(1,5)
value = round(runif(5)*100)
myDf <- data.frame(key,value)

#Transpose dataframe. This makes it a matrix so we convert it back into a data frame.
myDf <- as.data.frame(t(myDf))

#This creates two rows, one with key one with value

#If you want the column NAMES to be the key, then we can set the names to key, and drop the row containing the key
names(myDf) <- myDf["key",]
myDf <- myDf["value",]
```